# In Sublime Text 2, Tab button randomly flips between two actions

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've tried hard to find an answer for this but I couldn't find one anywhere.

I use Sublime Text 2 and use the Tab button to indent lines and also to select a suggested autocompleted word. However very often pressing the Tab button simply makes Sublime scroll to the end of the file. There seems to be no predictability in whether it chooses to scroll or actually indents a line or autocompletes as I want it to. As far as I can see this behaviour is completely random. Sometimes it indents and sometimes it scrolls. Any ideas as to what makes Sublime scroll down the document and what I can do to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: What plugins are you using?

Comment: `HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`, `JavaScript & NodeJS Snippets`, `Color Highlighter`, and maybe a few others. I code primarily in JavaScript btw, and use htmlprettify and the JS Snippets regularly.

Comment: I'm curious, how are you making Sublime use the Tab key to do two different things in the first place?

Comment: When I begin typing and Sublime gives a suggested snippet then Tab acts like Enter, selecting that snippet and writing it in the file. In all other cases it just acts as regular tab, adding a tab space.

Comment: Try upgrading to [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3) and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Won't that make all my current packages incompatible?

Comment: @Aron you'll need to reinstall Package Control first. Then, copy `Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` from ST2 to ST3 and your packages will automatically reinstall. Alternatively, just reinstall your packages in ST3.